Shopify app request not sending HMAC parameter
Building this Shopify app with Flask that interfaces with Facebook, but when Facebook redirects me through the callback I'm not getting an HMAC parameter for verification.
This is the validation function:
def is_valid_request(params, hmac_signature):

    parsed_params = dict(parse_qsl(params, keep_blank_values=True))
    
    # Remove the hmac parameter
    parsed_params.pop('hmac', None)
    
    # Reconstruct the query string without the hmac parameter
    msg = urlencode(sorted(parsed_params.items()))
    
    # Create a new HMAC and verify it against the provided value
    hmac_calculated = hmac.new(SHOPIFY_API_SECRET.encode('utf-8'), msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    if hmac_signature is None:
        print("hmac_signature is None.")
        return False

    return hmac.compare_digest(str(hmac_calculated), str(hmac_signature))

And this is the section of the Shopify callback that handles HMAC verification:
@app.route('/shopify/callback', methods=['GET'])
def callback():
    shop = request.args.get('shop')
    code = request.args.get('code')
    hmac_signature = request.args.get('hmac')
    # Validate the HMAC signature
    params = request.query_string.decode("utf-8")
    # Ensure the request is from Shopify

    if not is_valid_request(params, hmac_signature):
        print(is_valid_request(params, hmac_signature))
        return str("Invalid signature"), 403

After connecting with Facebook, it redirects to the Shopify callback route and shows a page that says "Invalid signature". I tried logging the signature to see what it looked like it was equal to "None". Printing out params variable shows a long string of text which I assume is supposed to have the HMAC parameter, but the only readable English is "code=" and "state=" followed by a bunch of random numbers and letters.
Am I doing something wrong? Should there be a different response from Shopify? There's no documentation in the Shopify dev docs on using Flask to build an app, so finding solutions is a little tough.
The full callback URL very clearly has two parameters that I can see: the code parameter and the state parameter. There is no HMAC parameter, like there should be.
Here is a URL redirect I get from the callback function:
https://appurl.com/shopify/callback?code=AQBKkiaVmjmD7HYsZ7CUz8cOvn8V_GSR3VzGsdLyOO419dG4p3qAajSzFrqO5sHAiMCcd1jfA-QbMBfSg_--oAFRNvNBQXhYOUJQoLcQRmT_SNxLnLvS5TyUlMG6fNip6xdhB44Md3mASORuDYOmFJ39jZvigUi9zfvTPsmMNXFmj8Df0JKtLJmm7lON7mvMqNMMGNC3fMHM8OY2dMHSR2U0HYN9NUci19zNGAJ3L0imOUhD4UXCTocRdUJLMxjkJYy7kO-bB1FG2fVVt13J8XLNy2BTZpHzvV-GPK-f8kXVQlUtUUmBfQfnynbtZss2VFxtpDjt0OMJs5Q4XNJix1UToUQ5OjzCHb1zMCfrpPsZ1phDmjo_BvAAMzsOb8HXp4O&state=b%27Xa%5Cx8d%5Cx91%5Cx88%5Cxf7%5Cx00%5Cxc4%5Cxa4V%5Cx00%5Cxf0%5Cx18%5Cxb6%5Cx8f%5Cxab%5Cxb1Z%60%5Cxdb4%5Cx01X%5CxO9%27#_=_
As you can see, the code parameter and state parameter can be seen here, but there's no hmac parameter.
